# Fast way to know compute parity of bitvector

Tags: c, bitvector

I am working with bitvectors in C. My bitvectors are `unsigned long long`'s. For a large number of vectors I need to know if the parity, i.e. the number of bits that are 1, is even or odd.

The exact value is not important, just the parity. I was wondering if there is anything faster than calculating the number of ones and checking. I tried to think of something, but couldn't find anything.

A short example of how I want this to work:

```
void checkIntersection(unsigned long long int setA, unsigned long long int setB){
    if(isEven(setA & setB)){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: search for "bit twiddling hacks" ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With divide and conquer technique:

```
uint64_t a = value;
a ^= (a >> 32);            // Fold the 32 MSB over the 32 LSB
a ^= (a >> 16);            // reducing the problem by 50%
a ^= (a >> 8);             // <-- this can be a good break even point
..
return lookup_table[a & 0xff];  // 16 or 256 entries are typically good
..
```

Folding procedure can be applied until the end:

```
a ^= (a >> 1);
return a & 1;
```

In IA the Parity flag can be directly retrieved after the reduction to 8 bits.

`a ^= (a >> 4);` makes another good point to stop dividing, since some processor architectures can provide parallel Look Up Tables `uint8_t LUT[16]` embedded into XXM (or NEON) registers. Or simply the potential cache misses of 256-entry LUT's can simply overweight the computational task of one extra round. It's naturally best to measure which LUT size is optimal in a given architecture.

This last table consists actually of 16 bits only and can be emulated with the sequence:

```
return ((TRUTH_TABLE_FOR_PARITY) >> (a & 15)) & 1;
```

where bit *N* of the magic constant above encodes the boolean value for *Parity(N)*.

Answer (score 1):

You could precompute in an array the parity for all possible combinations of bits in a byte:

```
bool pre[256] = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, ....}
```

When you need to find out the parity of a larger array you just do:

```
bool parity (long long unsigned x)
{   
    bool parity = 0;
    while(x)
    {   
        parity ^= pre[x&0xff];
        x>>=8;
    }
    return parity;
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code, it's just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy.  Something like

```
unsigned population(unsigned long long x) {
  x = ((x >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555) + (x & 0x5555555555555555);
  x = ((x >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333) + (x & 0x3333333333333333);
  x = ((x >> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) + (x & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f);
  x = (x >> 8) + x;  // Don't need to mask, because 64 < 0xff
  x = (x >> 16) + x;
  x = (x >> 32) + x;
  return x & 0xff;
}
```

should work.  Also, some CPUs have population count instructions (I don’t think x86 does, mind).

If you like this kind of thing, you should check out the book *Hacker’s Delight* by Henry S. Warren, Jr.

Comment: OP specifically wants something faster than counting the number of bits.